# Play slick application - connection leak

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

I am using play-slick in a play 2.1.3 application.
Here is the code to insert a record

```
  def insert = DBAction { implicit rs =>
    recordForm.bindFromRequest.fold (
        formWithErrors => {
          Redirect(HomePage).flashing("alert-error" -> "Enter proper values")
        },
        record => {
          Records.insert(record)
          Redirect(HomePage).flashing("alert-success" -> "Record inserted successfully")
        }
    )            
  }
```

The above code is leaking connection and the application throws the below error after 30+ requests

```
java.sql.SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:503) ~[bonecp.jar:0.7.1.RELEASE]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:114) ~[bonecp.jar:0.7.1.RELEASE]
    at scala.slick.session.PlayDatabase.createConnection(PlayDatabase.scala:9) ~[na:na]
    at scala.slick.session.BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(Session.scala:207) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at scala.slick.session.BaseSession.conn(Session.scala:207) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at scala.slick.session.Session$class.prepareStatement(Session.scala:29) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
```

Similar issues are reported, but this code is slightly different.
Any idea?

Comment: If this code is leaking connections, you might want to [raise an issue](https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/issues/new) for the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an instance of the bug "2)" described in https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/issues/81 . It is fixed in play-slick master and will be in the next release. The buggy code in play-slick is explained here [Play slick and Async - is it a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579684/play-slick-and-async-is-it-a-race-condition) . The bug triggers a follow-up bug in Slick, where instead of an exception thrown, the connection is leaked: https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/107

Comment: Yes, I cloned the latest play-slick code and pointed my app to it.  
Now it is working fine. Thanks.